# If $\cos^n(x)-\sin^n(x) = 1$ have $11$ roots in $ \left[0,\frac{23\pi}{2}\right)$. Then $n$ can be

Tags: trigonometry

If $\cos^n(x)-\sin^n(x) = 1$ have $11$ roots in $\displaystyle \left[0,\frac{23\pi}{2}\right)$. Then $n$ can be

Options: $(a)\; 1\;\;\;\; (b)\; 2\;\;\;\; (c)\; 3\;\;\;\; (d)\; 6$

Attempt: for all natural number $n\geq 1$

$$\cos^n (x) = 1+\sin^n x$$

$\star$ for $n\in 2k$ even natural number, $\cos^{2k} = 1+\sin^{2k}(x)$

equality hold when $\cos^{2k}(x) = 1\Rightarrow x=m\pi$ and $\sin^{2k}(x)=0\Rightarrow x=m\pi$

$\star$ for $n\in 2l+1$ even natural number, $\cos^{2l+1} = 1+\sin^{2l+1}(x)$

wan,t be able to go further, could some help me , thanks

Comment: Any way to turn this equation into one that only involves $\sin$ or $\cos$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When $n$ is odd in addition to the solutions you obtain when $n$ is even, you get those when $\cos x = 0$ and $\sin x = -1$ i.e. $x = (4n+3) \frac{\pi}{2}$

Answer (score 2):

Hari Shankar has already written an answer mentioning that $x=(4k+3)\frac{\pi}{2},2k\pi$ where $k\in\mathbb Z$ are solutions for $n$ odd.

(note that $x=(2k+1)\pi$ are solutions for $n$ even, but they aren't for $n$ odd.)

This answer proves that there are no other solutions for $n$ odd.

If $n=1$, then
$$1=(\cos x-\sin x)^2=1-2\cos x\sin x\implies \cos x=0\quad\text{or}\quad \sin x=0$$

If $n\ge 3$ is odd with $0\lt |\cos x|\lt 1$ and $0\lt |\sin x|\lt 1$, then
$$\begin{align}1&=|\cos^nx-\sin^nx|\\\\&\le |\cos^nx|+|\sin^nx|\\\\&\lt |\cos^2x|+|\sin^2x|\\\\&=\cos^2x+\sin^2x\\\\&=1\end{align}$$
which is impossible.

So, we have to have
$$|\cos x|=0,1\quad\text{or}\quad |\sin x|=0,1,$$
i.e.
$$\cos x=0\quad\text{or}\quad \sin x=0$$
for $n$ odd.

From these, we see that if $n$ is odd, then there are $11$ solutions in $\left[0,\frac{23\pi}{2}\right)$.